# Send ActiveAdmin Comments through ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin, actionmailer

I'm trying to accomplish the following...
When I create a new comment for a resource on ActiveAdmin panel, this comment should be sent by email to users who belong to that resource.

For example:

School has_many :students

Student belongs_to :school

So them, when I create a comment for School on ActiveAdmin, all students will get this comments thought email.

I already found out how to get the specific comment from a resource, for example:

comment = ActiveAdmin::Comment.where(resource: resource)

But I'm not sure what would be the best approach to accomplish my goal, if I should use a callback on School model, or, if somehow, I can trigger some action on the comment creation.

Answer (score 0):

An after_create on ActiveAdmin::Comment seems reasonable.

Comment: Hi Piers C, thanks for your help.
I ended up creating a ActiveAdmin.register ActiveAdmin::Comment to override the default create model on comments, and that's where I was able to call a method to send the comments as email.